# Sketching in the complex plane all complex numbers that satisfy two equations

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

There's one of these that I am completely stuck on.

The two equations referred to in the title are:

$\lvert Re(z-5)\rvert\leq1$  and   $Re(\frac{z}{\bar{z}})=1$

The second equation will always hold true because complex conjugate does nothing to it's real part.

From the first equation, I conclude easily enough that the interval is $x \in [4,6]$.

But that leaves me with an infinite amount of complex numbers on that interval without a defined imaginary part, and I don't know how to sketch those out.

Comment: Both relations must be fuflilled *together*, or you must write down *each case* separatedly?

Comment: They both have to be fulfilled together. Also, I corrected that bit about having three complex numbers, that was a mistake on my part. There's an infinite amount of them between 4 and 6.

Comment: Please correct the 2nd equation. It has an unmatched “$|$” delimiter.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\;z=a+ib\;,\;\;a,b\in\Bbb R\;$ , so:

$$z-5=(a-5)+ib\implies\left|\text{Re}\,(z-5)\right|=|a-5|\le1\iff 4\le a\le 6$$

and you have a pretty precise closed interval on the real axis.

Now,

$$\frac z{\overline z}=\frac{(a+ib)^2}{a^2+b^2}=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2}+i\frac{2ab}{a^2+b^2}\implies \text{Re}\,\frac z{\overline z}=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2}=1\implies\ldots\text{etc.}$$

Solve now.

Comment: The only think I can work out from that is that it will hold true if either of them is $0$. But 0 isn't in the closed interval, so the sketch is just a line on the real axis from 4 to 6?

Comment: The very last equality is pretty clear: it **must be** $\;b=0\;$ ...!